# Too much space between tables

Tags: spacing

I have these tables and it puts a lot of space between them. I can't figure out how to reduce this space.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\noindent\adjustbox{max width = \textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
\multicolumn{11}{|c|}{Poisson Distribution}\\
\hline
%data
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{This table shows the probability of the site crashing/not crashing and the number of iterations it took to do so (C/NC).}
\end{table}
% THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE NO SPACES BETWEEN TABLES.
\begin{table}
\noindent\adjustbox{max width = \textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}{ c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
\multicolumn{11}{|c|}{Uniform Distribution}\\
\hline
%data
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{This table shows the probability of the site crashing/not crashing and the number of iterations it took to do so (C/NC).}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try replacing `\end{table} ... \begin{table}` with `\par`.

Answer (score 3):

Use a single `table` environment, containing two `tabular` environments and two `\caption` directives. You probably do want *some* vertical whitespace between the two tabular chunks; if so, a directive such as `\vspace{1cm}` may achieve that objective.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\adjustbox{max width = \textwidth}{%
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
\multicolumn{11}{|c|}{Poisson Distribution}\\
\hline
%data
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{This table shows the probability of the site crashing\slash
not crashing and the number of iterations it took to do so (C/NC).}

\vspace{1cm} % <--- this is new

\adjustbox{max width = \textwidth}{%
\begin{tabular}{ c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
\multicolumn{11}{|c|}{Uniform Distribution}\\
\hline
%data
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{This table shows the probability of the site crashing\slash 
not crashing and the number of iterations it took to do so (C/NC).}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```